# Allow HTTP file server to be accessed over the internet without port forwarding

Tags: windows, http

I am running an HTTP file server on my Windows 10 PC that can only be accessed from my LAN. I don’t have the ability to port forward my router (lousy admin login) to make it accessible over the public internet. Is there a way, preferably a free way, of making my server accessible over the internet without port forwarding?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your router is your gateway between your LAN and the internet. Without port forwarding, you could try to use a DMZ feature of your router, which would effectively put a particular IP address the other side of your routers firewall.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way of making a http-server accessible over the internet without port forwarding?

Simple answer: no.

Complex answer: Yes, with VPN/RAT tools like freelan, teamviewer, ammyy and others - but not for the general public.

A (normal) computer *will* send a http-request to your routers WAN-IP. It's on him (eg his commanding administrator) to decide what to to with it (drop, reject, accep and forward ...).